# Transform Box from SR-ORG:6630 to WGS-84 in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I have an image file that I'm opening with gdal and using GetGeoTransform() to determine the minimum and maximum lats and lons:

```
Lon_Min=-2493045.0
Lon_Max=2342655.0
Lat_Max=3310005.0
Lat_Min=177285.0
```

I want to transform it to WGS-84.  I believe I've found how to do so using pyproj:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# project from SR-ORG6630 to ESPG4326 (WSG84)
# copied input projection from Proj4 format in http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6630/proj4/
inProj = Proj('+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

lon_min_coord, lat_min_coord = transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Min, Lat_Min)
lon_max_coord, lat_max_coord  = transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Max, Lat_Max)
```

This works fine without error; however, I noticed that depending on which corner of the box I use, I get a different result:

```
(Pdb) transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Max, Lat_Min)
(-73.59459648893585, 22.07673063064898)
(Pdb) transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Max, Lat_Max)
(-63.67219185074133, 49.177063191811406)
(Pdb) transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Min, Lat_Min)
(-119.78610533599247, 21.74230777798903)
(Pdb) transform(inProj, outProj, Lon_Min, Lat_Max)
(-130.2328280158085, 48.70739591346951)
```

For example, in the first two commands the only thing I changed was using Lat_Min vs using Lat_Max.  However, the output longitude was -73 then -63.  How do I know which coordinates to use in my transformation?

Comment: It's a conic projection. Longitude lines except the central meridian are tilted.Latitude lines are curved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script to reproject any raster.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')
old_ds = gdal.Open('raster.tif')
vrt_ds = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(old_ds, None, srs.ExportToWkt(), gdal.GRA_Bilinear)
ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('gtiff').CreateCopy('reprojected_raster.tif', vrt_ds)

ds.FlushCache()

del old_ds, vrt_ds, ds
```

Alternatively, you can use the `gdalwarp` command line utility as follows:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r bilinear -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -co COMPRESS=LZW raster.tif reprojected_raster.tif`

where

- `-t_srs` defines the target source reference system
- `-r` defines the resampling algorithm
- `-wo` adds a buffer of pixels around the map as it is reprojected, which helps prevent gaps in the output.
- `-co` passes a creation option to the driver (a lossless compression)
- `raster.tif` is the input filename
- `reprojected_raster.tif` is the output filename.

More info on: http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html